# how to configure Vuejs so that router is picked up

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to integrate vue-router in my app. In my admin.js, I have:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import AdminHome from '../admin/home.vue'
import AdminMetroArea from '../admin/metro-area.vue'


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    { path: '/metro-areas/', name: 'metro-areas', component: AdminMetroArea },
    { path: '/', component: AdminHome }
  ]
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const admin_home   = new Vue(AdminHome).$mount('#vue-admin-home');
})
```

and I call like:

```
<td>my metro: <router-link :to="{ name: 'metro-areas' }">{{metro_area.metro_area}}</router-link></td>
```

but I get the following error:

[image]

How do I configure my Vue app to pick up my router?

Answer (score 0):

the `Router` needs to be supplied to `Vue` during initialization, explicitly:

```
new Vue({
    router: Router
})
```

Where `Router` is your `import Router from '...path'`.

Answer (score 0):

In Main.js file do the following thing:

```
import router from './router'
```

where './router' would be the path of your router file.

then,

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  }
})
```

Than, supply it to the Vue in the same file (Main.js).   HAPPY CODING :)